# scala: programatically open and close an XML tag using literal syntax?

Tags: xml, scala

i'm writing an abstraction for creating XML in scala, and i'd like to be able to automatically close an XML tag once it is open. the desired syntax is flexible, but ideally it would look something like this:

```
tag <div> {
  // define more markup in here
  tag <br/>
  {
    // some expression that results in more XML tags
  }
}
```

where  is a (partial) XML literal and "tag" is a custom control structure -
instead of having to explicitly open and close tags like this:

```
<div> <br/> { /* some expression */ } </div>
```

i'd like to do this in a way that still lets me use XML literal syntax, as opposed to manually creating element by specifying the tag label as a string, for example. is this possible in any way with scala?

Comment: The xml literals are parsed by the compiler and this is pretty much guaranteed to *not* be parse-able by the compiler.

Comment: If you really want to do this, I guess you could write a compiler plugin: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/140

Comment: A syntax like "tag br { .... }" would be easily possible. If that suits your needs, I can write more in an answer.

Comment: @kim sure, i'd be curious to see what that looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using the new [Dynamic trait](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/Dynamic.html) in Scala 2.9. You will have to compile it with `-Xexperimental`. If you only need a certain number of tags(such as all html tags) you can do the same in 2.8 by writing one method per tag.

```
import scala.xml.{TopScope, Elem, Text, Node}
import scala.xml.NodeSeq.Empty

object tag extends Dynamic {
  def applyDynamic(tag: String)(children: Any) = {
    val node = children match {
      case node:Node => node
      case s:String => Text(s)
      case _ => Empty
    }
    Elem(null, tag, null, TopScope, node:_*)

  }

}

val xml = tag one { tag two {"three"} }

println(xml)
```

The code sample prints `<one><two>three</two></one>`.

Comment: interesting, can you explain how "one" in "val xml = tag one ..." is able to become a string as the argument of applyDynamic? it seems to me like scala would try to look up "one" as a value.

i searched through scala's mailing lists about whether Dynamic would be truly supported in the next release given that it's experimental, and couldn't find any definitive answer. do you have an information about that? thanks.

Comment: This is how it works: The Scala compiler looks for a method called one and can't find it. It then checks whether the class implements Dynamic and since it does, it passes the method name as a String to the applyDynamic method. It's very much like ruby's method_missing. I think it will still be experimental in scala 2.9 final, but so far it has worked well for me.